# In a Google SpreadSheet embedded in an iframe how to open hyperlinks inside the iframe instead of opening in new tab?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, google-sheets

I embedded a report made in Google Sheets in a web page. The report is very big, and has lots of pages so I added hyperlinks to ease navigation for the user.

The problem is that when I publish the spreadsheet, the hyperlinks open a new tab. They open the spreadsheet in the sheet they are pointing to, but I need everything to work inside the iframe.

Is there a way to make this work? I am trying to intercept the event that opens the new tab, but since the src is from google I can't listen for the click events. My thought was to ***preventDefault()*** when a link is clicked, parse the gid and parameters from the link, and change the src in the iframe. But I need a way to intercept the event.

Could there be some functionality in Google Sheets that can help?

Comment: At this point, You'll be better off re-creating a new web app with sheets as backend using sheets api/table charts using gviz api. There's no way you're going to legitimately bypass same origin policy in a reliable browser. If you must, You can try creating browser extensions/addons, which can access all of DOM and run client side scripts.

Comment: Yes, that was my conclusion as well... For now, I'm going to publish the report using excel and one drive. Hyperlinks work perfectly well there... Do you know of any nice tutorials or guides to use sheets as a backend? I didn't know it was possible.

Comment: It's not recommended to use sheets as a database. But for small data, try [table charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/table) using [tag:google-visualization]

Comment: Also, if privacy isn't a concern, You can just share the spreadsheet with view only permission.

Comment: Thanks, I am testing the iframe using the URL from the share link, and it looks like it can work... I know all this is not recommended, I already have the report in a proper database and I'm trying Google Data Studio and other tools, but the client wants to see the sheet, and what can I do... Until I convince them...